# Bug: Issues with Here Map request

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I have an issue to get the medias download links in a lookup request.

My lookup request is as below:

https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?source=sharing&id=s-Yz1yZXN0YXVyYW50O2lkPTI1MHUwOXdoLTcxZmE5ZDViODY2OTRhM2FiYmFiYzFkZWM2Y2FmMzViO2xhdD00OC44Njk0Njtsb249Mi4zMDM0NTtuPVpJVEk7bmxhdD00OC44Njk1ODtubG9uPTIuMzAzNTI7cGg9JTJCMzMxNDU2MzQ4NDg7aD0yYjBkMWU&X-Political-View=FRA&app_code=mycode&app_id=myappid&image_dimensions=w600-h600&show_content=wikipedia&show_refs=facebook,tripadvisor&size=25

When I use my apikey or appcode it doesn't retrieve the medias.

[image]

But when I use the token you use in here maps website https://wego.here.com/ I can retrieve the medias link. I did not change anything else.

[image]

How can it be possible?

Could you please fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to have a reply? If we can't have a fix on this issue we will need to think on another solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately this is from the previous version of the API. I'd try with the current version (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) although you won't get media data back.